# Change the color of legends in Charts in power View

Tags: powerview, powerbi, powerquery

Is it possible to change the color of the legends in Power View charts? i have been googling for some time now but could find a way.
I could make use of KPIs to have an indicator as in this link: 
http://www.powerpivotpro.com/2012/05/kpis-in-powerpivot-v2/
I want to add similar range for legend colors in charts.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are using Power View charts within Excel 2013 you can change the Theme from the Power View menu. For Power View on SharePoint this is under the Styles menu. These give you a little control over the range of colours used for legends and charts but still no control over what precise colour you want to use for what legend item.
This is by design ... Power View is designed for simplicity.

Comment: Yes, but if I have 3 charts in my Power View and the colors represent different variables (for example, Gender in charts 1&2 and Location in chart 3), then it is actually incorrect to show the same color... ESPECIALLY considering that everything is linked.